# Mongo+PHP Query How to check if an field is empty

Tags: php, arrays, mongodb, null, size

Data:

```
"field1" : { "sub_field" : [ ]}
```

I want to write a query to check if the 'sub_field' is empty or not.

This is what I tried:

```
$cursor = $collection->find( array('field1.sub_field' => array('$ne' => null))
```

Obviously it gives results as Array is not null (I have tried null and empty space  in futility).

I was told that '$size' operator can be used to achieve this. but I have had no luck so far.

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could approach this in a couple of ways. The first is to use the numeric array indexes in the query object keys using the dot notation and the **[`$exists`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/)** operator to search all documents that won't have at least a `sub_field` array element:

```
var cursor = db.collection.find({ "field1.sub_field.0": { "$exists": false } })
```

which should translate to PHP as

```
$cursor = $collection->find( array("field1.sub_field.0" => array("$exists" => false))
```

The other way would be to use the **[`$size`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/query/size/)** operator together with the **[`$exists`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/)** operator all wrapped within a **[`$or`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/nor/#op._S_or)** operator to find all documents without a `sub_field` either non existent or empty array:

```
var cursor = db.collection.find({
    "$or": [
        { "field1.sub_field": { "$exists": false } },
        { "field1.sub_field": { "$size": 0 } }
    ]
});
```

Another approach you could consider though with slower performance, would be to use the **[`$where`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/where/#op._S_where)** operator:

```
var cursor = db.collection.find({       
    "$where": "this.field1.sub_field.length == 0"   
});
```

For benchmark testing, try populating a test collection:

```
db.test.insert([       
    { field1: { sub_field: [] } },
    { field1: { sub_field: [ "foo" ] } },
    { field1: { sub_field: [ "foo", "bar" ] } }
]);

> db.test.find({ "field1.sub_field.0": { "$exists": false } })
> db.test.find({
    "$or": [
        { "field1.sub_field": { "$exists": false } },
        { "field1.sub_field": { "$size": 0 } }
    ]
})
> db.test.find({ "$where": "this.field1.sub_field.length == 0" })
```

All the three queries will yield the document that has an empty `sub_field` array:

```
/* 0 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("568ccec3653d87e43482c4d0"),
    "field1" : {
        "sub_field" : []
    }
}
```

Comment: I haven't tried the solution yet. but one note. The sub_field will never be null. it could be an empty array array(0). But never null. that's where I have the issue. I will try the solutions and post the results here.

Comment: The queries would still work nonetheless. I have removed the obsolete test cases and can confirm the result is still the same.

Comment: Thanks. even though I haven't resolved the issue, I am pretty much convinced that this is the way to go. when I tried '$where' condition with the 'length' option I received an error  :     "TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined near 'field.sub_field.length".  I am using Mongodb 2.6.11. is there any compatibility issues ?

Comment: No issues with 2.6.11 as far as I know. The error is most probably as a result of some documents which don't have the `sub_field` key, hence the `undefined` error.

Comment: This worked:  $cursor = $collection->find(array("field.sub_field.0" => array('$exists' => true)));

Answer (score 2):

for find type null or undefined field you can use this :

For undefined :

```
db.getCollection('your_collection_name').find({ yuorField: { $type: 6 } })
```

For null :

```
db.getCollection('your_collection_name').find({ yuorField: { $type: 10 } })
```

Comment: Its not a case of null value. its a case of empty array. How would we check if the array is empty or not in a query ?

Comment: The solution works for NULL value excellently. However I guess an empty array is not equivalent to 'undefined'. The return is always empty for $Type 6 checks.

Comment: it just check undefined and null fields.